# What is the name of use case of this type

Tags: manual-testing

Say there is feature that is accessible to different users using that they can submit the application if there is one unique id.

1. I have logged in as user-01 in one browser and clicked on the
   feature and entered the unique id and it auto-populate all the
   details but i haven't submitted the application I have kept the tab
   open.
2. Same the way for second user in different browser accessing the
   feature but application not submitted.

If user-01 submits the application acknowledgment is generated.
then user-02 can also submit it but should be validated not to submit.

**What is the name of this use case?**

Comment: What is your question? What type of test this is? How you should name the use case? Seems a functional requirement where records needs to be unique, how that is handled seems application specific.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a unique constaint. But I would discuss naming with your team. Naming things is hard and domain specific. Maybe [Domain Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) helps with naming functionality better.